# How do i debug svelte compiler?

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to build and debug svelte source code to learn svelte internal better.

The code runs as expected.
The problem appears when I use the svelte compiler on a plain old JavaScript file and trying to debug it with VSCode.

It seems that the debugger fails to read the source map file.

The debugger highlights / read compiler.js (compiled one) but I want to debug the .ts one instead of the compiled file.

Here's the code :

```js
// playsv.js
const sv = require('./compiler')
const str = '<h1>text</h1>'
// get ast
const ast = sv.parse(str)
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using `npm link` like this to use the local svelte package https://gist.github.com/unlocomqx/175225cedafc2b8c3d06686915f94930

Comment: Thank you, i will try and report as soon as possible.

Comment: @UnLoCo it work like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [@UnLoCo answer](https://gist.github.com/unlocomqx/175225cedafc2b8c3d06686915f94930).

I have to do is:

1. Clone `sveltejs/svelte`
2. `npm run build`
3. `npm link`
4. After that, go back to the project folder and run `npm link svelte`